# If -Else condition in Pandas to create CSV in separate folders

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, if-statement

I am new to python and trying to apply if-else condition over a dataframe.

If the ACCOUNT_LOGIN contains any special character create the  csv under a ErrorFolder.
else
create the csv under ValidatedDataFolder

But the below is also creating a file under ValidatedDataFolder alongwith ErrorFolder even .
How to acheive this validation of creating csv in different folders based on if-else condition?

dataframe
ACCOUNT_LOGIN : [
AL&L@WA,
ANGLIND,
ASIGAFU
]

ACTION : [
AL,
AN,
AS
]

Trans_Desc: [
JSW,
JSW,
JSW
]

```
def validate(rowsofdataframe):

filename="TestFileSpclCharOp.txt" 

if  rowsofdataframe['ACCOUNT_LOGIN_1'].strip().isalnum()==False : #if any row contains any spcl character
    output_error_file=os.path.join(errorPath,filename)
    rowsofdataframe.to_csv(output_error_file,index=False)
    val="Login contains special character.FAILED"
else :
   
    validated_Files=os.path.join(foramttedPath,filename)
    rowsofdataframe.to_csv(validated_Files,index=False)
    val="All validation passed" 
    
return val

dfwithcolumns['Status'] = dfwithcolumns.apply(validate, axis=1)
```

Comment: You can divide your original dataframe into two..One with error words and other without and save in different `csv`. Don't need apply here.

Comment: I am reading this dataframe from from another set of multiple csv. If one csv contains special character ,I need to process them and copy into Error folder...Else copy them into ValidatedFolder

Comment: You can load all your csvs in multiple dataframes and then can filter out those and save whatever you need. You don't need to go row by row and save each row in a csv.

Comment: Thanks . Exactly that is what I am looking for.How to filter out the entire dataframe based on a if condition rather than going by rows

Comment: Thanks.There are multiple csv in the input folder. I am trying to read each one of them one by one and put each one into a dataframes. If csv contains special chracters in Account_Login column the entire dataframe must get copied to error folder.

Comment: See the edited answer. Answer to the above problem. Change folder paths and names accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_folder_path = '/home/inp'
correct_files_folder = '/home/correct'
error_files_folder = '/home/error'
# All the multiple input files name in a list
input_file_names = ['a.csv', 'b.csv', 'c.csv']

# Looping over all files
for f in input_file_names:
    # Reading each file into a dataframe
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(input_folder_path, f))
    # Checking whether the column has any special characters or not. If it has one special character also then also it gets saved in error folder
    if df['ACCOUNT_LOGIN_1'].str.isalnum().sum()!=df.shape[0]:
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(error_files_folder, f), index=False)
    else:
        # No special character. Save in correct files folder
        df.to_csv(os.path.join(correct_files_folder, f), index=False)
```

Comment: The above solution is giving error "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'sum'"..Moreover this also does comparison over rows rather than entire dataframe as a whole.

Comment: This does comparison as you asked in the question. Comparison over column `ACCOUNT_LOGIN_1 `. You didn't asked to compare for whole dataframe. Please post question clearly.